# Making a matrix from several vectors

Tags: theano

Is it possible to make a Matrix out of several vectors in theano?

like:

```
vector1, vector2, vector3 = theano.tensor.vector()
Matrix = [vector1, vector2, vector3]
```

similar to the numpy operation:

```
Matrix = numpy.asarray([vector1, vector 2, vector3])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [theano.tensor.stack](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor.stack).

Here's a working example:

```
import theano
import theano.tensor as tt

vector1, vector2, vector3 = tt.vectors(3)
matrix = tt.stack(vector1, vector2, vector3)
f = theano.function([vector1, vector2, vector3], matrix)
print f([1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9])
```

where prints

```
[[ 1.  2.  3.]
 [ 4.  5.  6.]
 [ 7.  8.  9.]]
```